# creating rpm for two different hardware systems on Mageia

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild

I am trying to build rpm that will be installed in two different hardware devices.
For each hardware , there are different files and commands that need to be done, I want the rpm to auto-detect the hw according to its main-board type.

The changes are in install, post and files sections.

I am trying to set one global variable that will check the main board at the beginning and all the other sections use this variable in if statements to determine what to install.

I am aware that variables are normally not passed between sections , but I like think there is a workaround.

What I tried:

1. Set the variable from pre section with %global , the value doesn't
   pass to other section.
2. Set macro at the beginning of the spec file
   to read the main board (cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/board_name)
   but it appears empty in the other sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `spec` specifies two parts:

- commands to run on your **build-machine** in order to **build** the `rpm` (in your case the `%install` and `%files` sections)
- commands to run when **installing** the `rpm` on any **host** (in your case the `%post` section)

So you cannot share variables between these two parts.

Also when building a package, you would be checking your main board at build time (on your **build-machine**, not on the **host**. I would propose the following approach:

```
%install
# install here all files for all main-board types. for example:
cp board1 $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/lib/package/board1
cp board2 $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/lib/package/board2

%post
if [ "$(cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/board_name)" == "board1" ]
then
    ln -s /usr/lib/package/board1 /path/where/you/want/board-files
else
    ln -s /usr/lib/package/board1 /path/where/you/want/board-files
fi

%files
/usr/lib/package/board*
%ghost /path/where/you/want/board-files
```

Comment: Thank you , it works good , I was only hoping not to copy all files in each hardware to save the space.

Comment: I understand, but if you want one `rpm` for all systems, then that rpm must contain all data...